# How to get only the first n% of an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, slice

I have a sorted array like this:

> array [0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9];

I want to view only the first n% of the array. I need the principle or advice on what to use (loop, slice, ...) to achieve this.

Comment: Get the length of the array, calculate 20% of it, slice from 0 to that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could take the length of the array and the percent value and slice the array.

```js
function getPercent(array, percent) {
    return array.slice(0, Math.ceil(array.length * percent / 100));
}

var array = [0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9];

console.log(...getPercent(array, 10));
console.log(...getPercent(array, 20));
console.log(...getPercent(array, 30));
```

Comment: `16*20/100` will return `3.2` but `Math.ceil(16*20/100)` will return `4`. Is this is correct result ?

Comment: Damn. I literally did the exact same thing but you were faster ^^

Comment: @SudhirOjha, yes it is intentionally, because i thought, a greater number of elements could not be bad, especially with smaller arrays.